# Prevent Spring from attempting to read old resource stream

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, caching

I have a Spring Boot MVC application where I serve content packaged in OSGi bundles. The goal behind using OSGi is to make these content bundles fully self-contained and hot-swappable.

Requests are mapped to bundle resources via the url.

The problem I'm running into happens when I replace a bundle with a new one that would be pointed to by the same URL and a request comes in for a resource that had been served from the old bundle.

Spring sees that it has already returned a resource for that URL and so attempts to open the stream for the cached bundle URL it has to determine when the resource was last modified, which is now associated with the now-unavailable bundle and throws an `IOException`.

Everything I have found so far involves modifying the client-side caching policy, not the Spring internal cache. Additionally, trying to disable the cache via `spring.resource.chain.caching` or `spring.resources.cache-period` do not work, as Spring still tries to figure out the last modified timestamp regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there is a configuration for this, in an unexpected place.

In my WebMvcConfigurerAdapter-extending config class, in the `addResourceHandlers` method:

```
registry.addResourceHandler("**/pluginresource/**")
.setCacheControl(CacheControl.noStore() )
.resourceChain(false)
.addResolver(pluginResourceResolver);
```

`resourceChain(false)` actually sets whether or not Spring will create the chain with a default handler that makes use of caching.